# ionic view is not cached, controller reloads

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app with some views, when I start the app I will go to my main view, when the controller of the view is initialized I will load some data.

The problem is, when I navigate from that view, using tabs, that controller is **sometimes** destroyed, so when I navigate back the data will have to load again.

I have done some testing with *'$ionicView.loaded'* and *'$ionicView.unloaded'* and it seems to be pretty random when the view is unloaded.

This is my state configuration

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider

  .state('login', {
    name: "login",
    url: "/login",
    templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
    controller: 'loginCtrl'
  })

  // This is a sidemenu
  .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html'
  })

  .state('app.hms', {
    url: '/hms',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/hms-app.html',
        controller: 'HmsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.hms-item', {
    url: '/hms/:hmsId',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/hms-item.html',
        controller: 'HmsItemCtrl'
      }
    },
    params: {
      item: null
    }
  })

  .state('app.history', {
    url: '/history',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/history-list.html',
        controller: 'HistoryCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.history-item', {
    url: '/history/:itemId',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/history-item.html',
        controller: 'HistoryItemCtrl'
      }
    },
    params: {
      itemId: null
    }
  })

  .state('app.event-new', {
    url: '/event/new',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/event-new.html',
        controller: 'EventCtrl as ctrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.risk-new', {
    url: '/risk/new',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/risk-new.html',
        controller: 'RiskCtrl as ctrl'
      }
    }
  });


// if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
// this is also the first page, 'front page'
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login');

});
```

My tabs are defined in each .html template I need them in (so not the login page, for instance), they are defined after the closing of ion-content:

```
  <div class="tabs tabs-icon-top">
<a class="tab-item" href="#/app/hms">
  <i class="icon ion-home"></i>
  Home
</a>
<a class="tab-item" href="#/app/event/new">
  <i class="icon ion-document-text"></i>
  Hendelse
</a>
<a class="tab-item" href="#/app/risk/new">
  <i class="icon ion-document-text"></i>
  Risikorapport
</a>
<a class="tab-item" href="#/app/history">
  <i class="icon ion-ios-list"></i>
  Historikk
</a>
```

What could cause the controller of the view to be destroyed when I navigate from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, Ionic removes caching for views that are "forward", so when navigating back from a forward view that $scope will be destroyed.

This is explained under caching [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/directive/ionNavView/)

> By default, when navigating back in the history, the “forward” views are removed from the cache. If you navigate forward to the same view again, it’ll create a new DOM element and controller instance. Basically, any forward views are reset each time. This can be configured using the $ionicConfigProvider:

So, configuring the `$ionicConfigProvider` with `$ionicConfigProvider.views.forwardCache(true);` fixed my issue

I also saw I could fix my issue another way, and that was to not make my views "forward", when navigating to a new view using href, we can specify what sort of view that should be, by doing `nav-direction="swap"`, available directions are `forward, back, enter, exit, and swap`

Example of tab, with direction

```
<a class="tab-item" nav-direction="swap" nav-transition="android" href="#/app/home">
  <i class="icon ion-home"></i>
  Home
</a>
```